# Pressure dependence with depth in an incompressible fluid on a microscopic level

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

In beginning physics we learn that pressure in an incompressible fluid, in a gravitational field, varies with depth as $\rho g h$.

On a microscopic level, how is the pressure gradient in the fluid realized? In a gas, I guess it's just the classical kinetic theory, more collisions due to increased density or temperature at depth. The interactions leading to the gradient - collisions - are transitory and random; most of the time the gas molecules aren't interacting. In a solid, I can see that there might be some kind of equilibrium compression in the lattice which transmits force vertically (on average) through the material. The gradient is from interactions which are "permanent" and structured.

Liquids don't seem to set up the gradient like gases do, but also wouldn't seem to have any structured/permanent force transmission like solids. What is the correct picture? I am imagining intermolecular repulsions which exist in permanent state, on average, yet each of which arises from transitory interactions as the molecules slip by each other. Since the repulsions' directions are random, in order to set up the gradient, we need some variation with depth. Perhaps in fact the fluid is not truly incompressible, but the density is very slightly higher at depth? If this is correct, any pointers towards a mathematical model which leads to a simple formula like $\rho g h$? Is temperature variation also a part of this? I've read about Lennard-Jones, van der Waals, Tait, etc models, but it's not clear which best applies to, say, a glass of water on my desk.

Thanks

Comment: There is a good discussion about this subject in https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/595362/195949

Comment: In don't understand the core of your question. The pressure gets greater with depth for obvious reasons, there is more stuff pushing down with greater force due to gravity, be it gas, liquid, solid, plasma or any other phase. Microscopic models will all account for the macroscopic pressure forces by taking into account microscopic forces of interaction between all particles. The macroscopic phase seems irrelevant to this. Liquids may differ from gases in that they are less compressible, but there are still molecules and intermolecular forces.

Comment: Jan, "stuff pushing down" is too hand wavey for me. In a solid, the "pushing" is transferred through permanent lattice of molecules and intermolecular forces. In a gas, the pressure gradient is due to the changes in density (and temperature) created by the gravitational field, not "pushing". In a liquid, one bit of matter is affected by being under a lot of other matter, but the higher matter does not interact with it directly. What is the exact mechanism by which the higher matter affect what is below it, on a microscopic level, in a liquid?