# Is hydrostatic pressure gradient due to density gradient?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-statics

Assuming an incompressible fluid, as is often done, the hydrostatic pressure law is derived: $p = p_0 + \rho g h$. I have a qualitative question: is it correct to say that as depth increases, the increased pressure is due, "microscopically", to the increased density of the fluid? And does that mean that the "incompressible fluid" assumption is in a sense convenient, but incoherent?

I understand that the high [bulk modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus) of fluids such as water means that very high pressure is needed to increase the density even a little. However, it occurs to me that at the depth where there's a substantial pressure according to the formula $\rho g h$, the way the water molecules or a submerged body "feels the column of weight pressing on it" is only by the local contact with the water at around that depth, **which has to be more compressed, i.e. more dense, to generate that pressure**; and even if it's just a little more dense, that's enough to generate very high pressure precisely due to the high bulk modulus.

I guess I'm looking for a validation of this point of view, since I haven't had luck in finding it explicitly stated in several textbooks on fluid mechanics I've looked at. They have little trouble deriving a pressure gradient for a homogenous fluid where density is assumed to be constant throughout.

Is it correct to say that the pressure gradient is caused by the fluid being more and more compressed at greater depths, which is evidenced by its density gradient? Or are there other factors than density and compression which cause the pressure to increase with depth?

Comment: Density is a bulk property of a fluid.  For incompressible fluids, the density doesn't vary with depth.

Comment: @DavidWhite thanks for your comment. I'm aware of what "incompressible" means, and addressed this in the question.

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/600868/pressure-dependence-with-depth-in-an-incompressible-fluid-on-a-microscopic-level